# 16x2 LCD displaying blocks when connected with MCP23017 on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi2, lcd

I am using a 16x2 LCD and have it connected with MCP23017 16-bit IO port expander. To display message to the LCD, I am using Adafruit LCD library. They also have a test python code to get it working with MCP23017. I have changed the pin according to the connections I have made but it seems to be displaying only blocks in the first row of the LCD. I tried different pins, but I can't get it to work.

LCD: http://www.ebay.in/itm/16x2-Character-LCD-Module-HD44780-JHD-Black-on-Green-Backlight-Berg-Strip-/221634648684?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item339a745a6c

Adafruit library: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/tree/master/Adafruit_CharLCD (Here I am using LCD_MCP230XX_test.py file to test my setup).

Is there something or some configuration I am missing?

Comment: That is an indication that the display isn't being initialized correctly.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Thanks! The example has the code to initialize the display. Is there something else I have to do to get it to work?

Comment: I think this looks suspiciously like commercial spam from Adafruit, I've seen a lot of links to either their store, or they products named by brand name recently. Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: On the other hand this should be closed as off-topic as it is asking for pin configuration and is not about programming. Also it displays minimal knowledge about the topic and uses python just as a way to be at StackOverflow